# ORDER in CTE lost after GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL

```
WITH tally AS (
    SELECT results.answer,
           results.poll_id,
           count(1) AS votes
    FROM (
             SELECT pr.poll_id,
                    unnest(pr.response) AS answer
             FROM poll_responses pr
                      LEFT JOIN polls p ON pr.poll_id = p.id
                      LEFT JOIN poll_collections pc ON pc.id = p.poll_collection_id
             WHERE pc.id = ${pollCollectionId}
         ) AS results
    GROUP BY results.answer, results.poll_id
),

     all_choices AS (SELECT unnest(pls.choices) AS choice,
                            pls.id              AS poll_id
                     FROM poll_collections pcol
                              INNER JOIN polls pls
                                         ON pcol.id = pls.poll_collection_id
                     WHERE pcol.id = ${pollCollectionId}),

     unvoted_tally AS (SELECT ac.choice AS answer,
                              ac.poll_id,
                              0         AS total
                       FROM all_choices ac
                                LEFT JOIN tally t ON t.answer = ac.choice
                       WHERE t.answer IS NULL),

     final_tally AS (SELECT *
                     FROM tally
                     UNION
                         ALL
                     SELECT *
                     FROM unvoted_tally),

     sorted_tally AS (
         SELECT ft.*
         FROM final_tally ft
         ORDER BY array_position(array(SELECT choice FROM all_choices), ft.answer)
     )

SELECT json_agg(poll_results.polls) AS polls
FROM (
         SELECT json_array_elements(json_agg(results)) -> 'poll' AS polls
         FROM (
                  SELECT json_build_object(
                                 'id', st.poll_id,
                                 'question', pls.question,
                                 'choice-type', pls.choice_type,
                                 'results',
                                 json_agg(json_build_object('choice', st.answer, 'votes', st.votes)),
                                 'chosen', pr.response
                             ) AS poll
                  FROM sorted_tally st
                           LEFT JOIN polls pls
                                     ON
                                         pls.id = st.poll_id
                           LEFT JOIN poll_responses pr
                                     ON
                                         pr.poll_id = st.poll_id AND
                                         pr.email = ${email}
                  GROUP BY st.poll_id, pls.choice_type, pr.response, pls.question
              ) AS results)
         AS poll_results;
```

I have a `poll_responses` table which store the user responses of a `poll`. I want to order the responses in exactly the same order they are stored in the `polls` table - as an array e.g., `{Yes, No, Maybe}`.

I applied the `ORDER BY array_position(array(SELECT choice FROM all_choices), ft.answer)` in the `sorted_tally` CTE.

However, in the file `SELECT` after applying `GROUP BY` the order is lost.

Is there a way to preserve the order of the `choices`?

Also, are there any optimizations applicable?

Much appreciated!

Comment: `ORDER BY` only counts in the outermost query.  It doesn't count in CTEs or subqueries or views.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Any edits you suggest?

Comment: There's no order in a relational table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `json_build_object` or `json_agg` you can set `ORDER BY` clause. First, have the last CTE `SELECT` needed order expression as a new column, then run in outermost query:

**CTE**

```sql
...
sorted_tally AS (
     SELECT ft.votes
          , ft.poll_id
          , ft.answer
          , array_position(array(SELECT choice FROM all_choices), 
                           ft.answer) AS choice_order
     FROM final_tally ft
     ORDER BY 
 )
```

**Outermost Query**

```sql
...
json_build_object(
       'id', st.poll_id,
       'question', pls.question,
       'choice-type', pls.choice_type,
       'results', json_agg(json_build_object('choice', st.answer, 
                                             'votes', st.votes)
                           ORDER BY st.choice_order),
       'chosen', pr.response
    ) AS poll
```

Comment: Shouldn't I set `ORDER BY` in `json_agg` instead? Because I think you can only use `ORDER BY` in an aggregate function.

Comment: Give it a try. Did `ORDER BY` in `json_build_object` not work?

Comment: I did. Didn't work. Failed with a runtime error. Although it works if I set `ORDER BY` in the `json_agg`.

Comment: Got it. Edited accordingly. With data, I could have tested.

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` in a CTE doesn't really matter.  It *may* work, but SQL Server is free to re-order the rows unless you specify `ORDER BY` in the outermost query to order all the results.

Comment: You need to have the value you want to sort by in your results, can you select `array_position` in sorted_tally instead of ordering by it and use that in the order by where you want to sort?